# How can I hide the command window in c?

Tags: c, gcc

I have a simple c program that makes a window pop up with some words. It wouldn't let me post the code but its pretty simple. And the command window pops up in the background every time I run it. I used gcc compiler. Is their any way to hide or terminate the command window?

Comment: You left out a pretty important piece of information. Can you guess what it is?

Comment: Sure thing. Look at the source, find the problem and fix it.

Comment: Which platform are you on?  It sounds like it might be Windows, but you should most certainly say what it is because the mechanisms for Windows will be different from those that might be relevant on Unix.

Comment: You can try using the terminfo library if it's there. It uses the header **term.h**.

Comment: Link with -mwindows flag.